# Using gtest to check correct initialization values of constructor

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

I'm new to cpp and gtest. 
I want to use gtest to check my cpp Board class with invalid 
Arguments, for example: negative number of rows,  to check that the invalid Arguments exception 
Is thrown, what will be the best way to do that?
Thought about try and catch bloc that catches the invalid 
Arguments exception, and if it is caught then the tests should pass, but I couldnt find no pass macro for gtest.

Answer (score 1):

Gtest has macros for that purpose, eg

```
ASSERT_ANY_THROW(statement);
```

asserts that `statement` throws (any) exception. See [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md) for more options (eg. asserting on only specific exceptions).